# Is 40 degrees Celsius a bad temperature for a router?

Tags: cpu, temperature, pfsense

I turned my old gaming pc into a pfsense machine. I never had cpu problems when I used that pc but now when I check the diagnostics on the pfsense gui, the cpu is running at 40 degrees. That's troubling to me because my new gaming pc runs at 30 degrees when I'm playing games and ~25 degrees when it's idle. My new gaming pc has the graphics card in it and the pfsense box doesn't. Just 16gb of ram and a cpu(i3 2100) and a 500gb hdd. Since its only 20 dollars on amazon I'm tempted to buy a cpu cooler but I don't know if that will solve the problem.

I don't know if it's normal for a router cpu to be running at 40 degrees, especially when my active pc doesn't go higher than 30 degrees when I'm using it for games.

It's a home network so it's not like I'm supplying 5000 connections on a campus. It's just my desktop and 7 WiFi devices.

When I check the CPU usage, half of the time it says 0% and the highest I've seen it go is 7%

Comment: What's the CPU load on the router? For 100% the temperature might be normal; for 2-3% it might mean it's time to clean the dust.

Comment: @grawity edited my question. Usage is 0% and the load average is 0.02 0.01 0.00. I'm not sure what that means. I'm guessing it's highest lowest and average load? And I cleaned the dust out a few weeks ago when I turned it into a router

Comment: It's the average load [per 1 minute, 5 minutes, and 15 minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)#Unix-style_load_calculation).

Comment: if you cleaned out the dust and removed the heatsink, you may have forgotten to apply new thermal paste to the cpu, which would be why the temps are suddenly high when they never were before

Comment: I actually didn't know I was supposed to reapply the thermal paste. I thought the remaining paste was still effective. I took apart the machine though and blew out the little dust that was in there and reapplied the paste. It does seem to be bringing the temp back down

Comment: Thermal paste tends to get thicker over time as heat drives out its moisture and volatile organic compounds. It still conducts heat just fine, but it is no longer capable of squeezing into microscopic gaps. If you "crack" the connection between the CPU and the heatsink, old thermal paste will not be able to reflow and properly reform that connection. If you have no other choice, you can thin it out with a tiny fraction of a drop of water, but it's much better to apply new thermal paste and even better than that to clean both surfaces thoroughly before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no.

While a high temperature might damage components or lower their life expectation, 40°C is miles away from being critical or even troubling.

In fact, as fast as I know, most modern processors would shut down at around 100°C to prevent damage. Their actual efficiency increases with temperature till around 70°C. [You can find some user collected data and graphs here.](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2200205)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with 40 degrees at all:
http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/desktop-pc/what-is-ideal-cpu-temperature-image-3498564/

A lot of CPUs can actually handle a significantly hotter temperature.. the Intel i7 can do over 100:
http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/232/Intel_Core_i7_Mobile_i7-5550U_vs_Intel_Core_i7_i7-4790K.html

If you are in doubt, take a look at the CPUWorld link aboe - they have writeups on quite a few CPUs and you may well find the spec sheet for yours listed there.

Also, it is worth noting that a lot of modern processors can adjust their workload and slow themselves down when they are getting too hot and have a builtin thermal cutout which will shut them down in the event they get too hot - which will prevent any damage to your kit.

If you are still worried about the temperature of your machine, invest ing good quality thermal paste and make sure your heatsink and fan are nice and clean.